# Unable to locate dynamic elements through webdriver

Tags: java, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate an dynamic element and check the checkbox. Once the checkbox is checked,  automatically the list receives the value 1 . I’ve tried xpath `/css`, but without any result.

**DOM** :

```
<table class="bulk_task_table">
<tbody>
<tr class="table_row">
<td class="servicenamewrapper">
<td style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; width:0;"></td>
<td style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; width:0;"></td>
<td class="skill_name" width="160px">
<div id="c23743691548_ctl" style="display:inline;">
<div id="c23743691548" class="skillwrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
<span id="c525_ctl">
<div class="renderWithName">
<div class="left">
<label for="c525">service</label>
</div>
<div class="right">
<input id="c525" class="skill48" name="c525" type="checkbox">
</div>
</div>
</span>
<span id="c526_ctl">
<select id="c526" class="listbox skill48" name="c526" size="1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<tr class="table_row">
<td class="servicenamewrapper"> </td>
<td class="skill_name">
<td class="skill_name">
<td class="skill_name">
<div id="c529_ctl" style="display:inline;">
<div id="c529" class="globalswitchwrapper">
<span id="c530_ctl">
<div class="renderWithName">
<div class="left">
<label for="c530">Service</label>
</div>
<div class="right">
<input id="c530" class="skill48" name="c530" type="checkbox">
</div>
</div>
</span>
<span id="c531_ctl">
<select id="c531" class="listbox skill48" name="c531" size="1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

OBS: As it can view in the above code, there are two lists called "service"with the same class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the desired dynamic elements based on their order of occurrences. For example, if you want to select the first occurring check box, you can use following **xpath**:

```
//table[@class='bulk_task_table']/descendant::input[starts-with(@class, 'skill')][1]
```

Similarly, if you want to select the second occurring checkbox, you can use the following xpath:

```
//table[@class='bulk_task_table']/descendant::input[starts-with(@class, 'skill')][2]
```

Moreover, in the same way, you can select other controls that are appearing in the dynamic element. For example, if you want to select the second occurrence of **select** control, you can use following xpath:

```
//table[@class='bulk_task_table']/descendant::select[starts-with(@class, 'listbox skill')][2]
```

If required, you can parameterize the predicate ([]) value as well. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks @Mahipal for the help offered , the given xpath has solve my error.